# Striped tab does not stay 100% after changing its height

Tags: html, css, ionic-framework, sass

If I change my tab through these ways:

```
.tab-x {
    .tab-nav {
        height: 75px !important;
    }
}
```

Or

```
$tabs-height:                     75px !default;
```

The strip of the tab does not stay at 100% width.

Follow the image for a better understanding:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/qTu36.jpg

Thanks all

EDIT:

Html view:

```
<ion-pane>
<ion-tabs class="tabs-icon-top tabs-striped tabs-color-royal tab-x">
     <ion-tab title="Follow" icon="flaticon-user flaticon-user-tab">
        <ion-view>
            <ion-content class="bg-mycareer content-tab-mycareer">
            </ion-content>
        </ion-view>
    </ion-tab>

    <ion-tab title="View" icon="flaticon-browser-visualization flaticon-browser-visualization-tab">
    <ion-view>
        <ion-content class="bg-mycareer content-tab-mycareer">
        </ion-content>
    </ion-view>
  </ion-tab>
</ion-tabs>
```

Sass:

```
.tab-x {
    .tab-nav {
        height: 75px !important;
    }
}
```

The problem:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/9ELx6.jpg

The striped does not occupy the full width of the tab, as I showed with the red arrow

Comment: Could you please post more of your code, so we can have a better understanding of what is going wrong.

Comment: I don't believe the stripe was ever supposed to be 100%. It highlights the active tab, and even with the default style the tab's bottom border shown the same as your screenshot.